# Android 2D opengl line circle

Tags: android, opengl-es, geometry

I am new to open gl, and have been trying to do some basic 2d openGL in android.  I am able to set up my 2D view, and draw squares and triangles.  I am trying to draw a circle and am not exactly sure how to do it.  I have found several techniques while searching, one using triangles rotated around the center w/ the given radius, this will not work as I do not want a filled circle.  I also found other suggestions to do this with lines moving around the outer edge of the circle.

I have chosen to implement the latter.  The issue I am having is with the IndexBuffer that is passed into glDrawElements, if my circle(lines) buffer has too many points, I am unable to create the byte array to create the IndexBuffer, as the maximum value for a byte is 127, any help or direction on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an IntBuffer, that should allow you to use as many indices as you'll ever need.